# Objective-C Split()?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, function, split

Is there any way to split strings in objective c into arrays? I mean like this - input string Yes:0:42:value into an array of (Yes,0,42,value)?

Answer (score 211, accepted):

```
NSArray *arrayOfComponents = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
```

where yourString contains `@"one:two:three"`

and arrayOfComponents will contain `@[@"one", @"two", @"three"]`

and you can access each with `NSString *comp1 = arrayOfComponents[0];`

(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1413214-componentsseparatedbystring)

Comment: Note the inverse is `[NSArray componentsJoinedByString:]`.

Comment: I have a problem if I do @"Hello world ". It will return an array of 3 objects, of which the last one contains @"". I could loop through array and delete it, but is there a better way?

Comment: @AuRis try trimming the whitespace from the string first: [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

Answer (score 95):

Try this:

```
    NSString *testString= @"It's a rainy day";
    NSArray *array = [testString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

Answer (score 6):

Try [componentsSeparatedByString:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-componentsSeparatedByString_)

Answer (score 4):

Use this:
[[string componentsSeparatedByString:@","][0];

Comment: I still wonder why people answer questions that are AGES old and have established answers... Not to mention yours just selects the first element which makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

if you want access first word:

```
[[string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
```