# Split before and after every , in a string and add to array

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Basically i want to split out everything inbetween the commas and add to an array and then get the count of this array and return it too.

I know its a mouthfull but someone will understand :P

Thanks

Mason

Comment: Functions usually do not return multiple values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSString tokenize in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259956/nsstring-tokenize-in-objective-c). The accepted answer returns an array of tokens. Getting the count from that should be obvious.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C Split()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558888/objective-c-split)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one:

```
-(NSInteger)countTotalWord:(NSString *) localString{
    //NSString *localString = @"My, Name, Is,Sudesh,Kumar ";
    //NSMutableArray *simplefyWordArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *wordSet = [localString  componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
   //for (int i=0 ;i<[wordSet count]; i++) {
       //NSString *trimedString = [[wordSet objectAtIndex:i] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
       //[simplefyWordArray appendFormat:@"%@+",trimedString];
    //}
    return [wordSet count];
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly in future, your post was almost completely unreadable.

Answer (score 5):

use componentsSeparatedByString: